# Elastic Search: return matching parents with matched/unmatched childs

Tags: elasticsearch, join, search, parent-child

I am using elastic search 7.8.1 and have used parent-child method to index the documents. My requirement is to search both parent and child documents, but return response in a format that parent document is the main document and child document is a field within the parent document. i.e

```
1) If the child matches, I wish to return parent & child in a document. I am able to achieve this using has_child and inner_hits.
2) If the parent matches the query, I wish to return parent and child in a document even if the child does not matches. (Not sure how to achieve this)

# This is the parent child relationship mapping in index
*curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "my_join_field": { 
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "question": "answer" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'*
    
Below is the query I am trying to use, but it does not return the child when the parent matches:
*curl -X POST "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "answer",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "my_id": "4"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "size": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "my_id": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'*
```

#Parent docs curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_doc/1?refresh&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "my_id": "1", "text": "This is a question", "my_join_field": "question" } ' curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_doc/2?refresh&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "my_id": "2", "text": "This is another question", "my_join_field": "question" } '

#Child docs curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_doc/3?routing=1&refresh&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "my_id": "3", "text": "This is an answer", "my_join_field": { "name": "answer", "parent": "1" } } ' curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_doc/4?routing=1&refresh&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "my_id": "4", "text": "This is another answer", "my_join_field": { "name": "answer", "parent": "1" } } '

How can I search both parent and child, but return child as a field in parent doc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the edit option on your Question to add information. Don't use comments for this.